# Mysql return value with nested Select

Tags: mysql, join, nested-select

I am writing some software for a restaurant. They change prices on certain dates. I have two tables, one with the products ordered by order, and another with prices, historical, that is, every time they change a price, I set a bit to 0 to the old value, create new entry and assign bit 1 into "valid" column.
I use the following MySQL code to recall the valid actual price:

`

```
SELECT 
`tbl_precios_productos`.`dbl_precio`
    FROM `tbl_precios_productos` 
    left join `tbl_prods_x_orden` on `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_producto_id` = `tbl_precios_productos`.`id_producto`
    where `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_producto_id` = `tbl_precios_productos`.`id_producto`
    and `tbl_precios_productos`.`bit_activo` = 1
    And `tbl_precios_productos`.`int_tipo_precio` = 1
    and `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_producto_id` = 10 /* this is the ID of the product */
    GROUP BY `tbl_precios_productos`.`dbl_precio`
```

`

When I try to nest that code into a bigger one, it doesn't work. Here is what I tried:
`

```
SELECT   
ANY_VALUE( `tbl_productos`.`id_producto`) AS `ID Prod`,  
ANY_VALUE( `tbl_productos`.`chr_nombre_prod`) AS `Producto`,  
SUM(ANY_VALUE( `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_cantidad`)) AS `Cantidad`, 
(SELECT 
`tbl_precios_productos`.`dbl_precio`
    FROM `tbl_precios_productos` 
    left join `tbl_prods_x_orden` on `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_producto_id` = `tbl_precios_productos`.`id_producto`
    where `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_producto_id` = `tbl_precios_productos`.`id_producto`
    and `tbl_precios_productos`.`bit_activo` = 1
    And `tbl_precios_productos`.`int_tipo_precio` = 1
    and `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_producto_id` = `tbl_precios_productos`.`id_producto`
    GROUP BY `tbl_precios_productos`.`dbl_precio`) AS `Precio`,
ANY_VALUE( `tbl_tipos_precios`.`id_tipo_precio`) AS `Tipo Precio`,  
ANY_VALUE( `tbl_tipos_precios`.`chr_nombre_precio`) AS `CHRTipoPrecio`,  
ANY_VALUE( `tbl_ordenes_cerradas`.`int_forma_pago`) AS `ID TPago`,  
ANY_VALUE( `tbl_formas_pago`.`chr_forma_pago`) AS `Tipo Pago`,  
ANY_VALUE( `tbl_productos`.`fl_ordenar`) AS `Ordenar`  
From  `tbl_prods_x_orden` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_productos` ON `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_producto_id` = `tbl_productos`.`id_producto` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_precios_productos` ON (((`tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_producto_id` = `tbl_precios_productos`.`id_producto`) And ( `tbl_precios_productos`.`int_tipo_precio` = 1)))
LEFT JOIN `tbl_precio_tipo_ordenes` ON `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_orden_id` = `tbl_precio_tipo_ordenes`.`id_orden`  
LEFT JOIN `tbl_tipos_precios` ON `tbl_tipos_precios`.`id_tipo_precio` = `tbl_precio_tipo_ordenes`.`id_tipo_precio`  
LEFT JOIN `tbl_ordenes_cerradas` ON `tbl_ordenes_cerradas`.`id_orden_id` = `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`int_orden_id`  
left join `tbl_formas_pago` ON `tbl_ordenes_cerradas`.`int_forma_pago` = `tbl_formas_pago`.`id_forma_pago`  
WHERE  `tbl_productos`.`int_activo` = 1  
And `tbl_prods_x_orden`.`bool_activo` = '1'  
and `tbl_ordenes_cerradas`.`int_forma_pago` = 3
And `tbl_ordenes_cerradas`.`id_control_fecha` >= 101  
And `tbl_ordenes_cerradas`.`id_control_fecha` <= 101
group BY `ID Prod`, `Tipo Precio`, `ID TPago`  
order by `Ordenar`
```

`
I get an error that the subquery returns more than one result. How can I get the specific valid price from the prices table using the id of the product. Imagine prices table with 4 columns: id, id_producto, valid, date_set. Sorry some of the code is in spanish, that is my mother language and what I am using to program, but I hope you get the idea.
Am I doing it correctly or is there any other way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you do a select, you are returning rows of values, so you can't have a column that is actually multiple rows.   So generally speaking you will need to move this subselect into the FROM section of the query.   You may be entering "correlated subquery" territory which is an advanced SQL topic.   You might just as easily sort this out in the application layer if your datasets are small.

Comment: I will start studying some more MySQL and read about those correlated subqueries. Thanks for the answer.